# ¿Cómo consigo hacer bindParam desde esta clase?

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo este archivo que me conecta a mi base de datos: `conDB.class.php`

```
<?php

    function __autoload ($classname)
    {
        $filename = "" . $classname . ".class.php";
        include_once($filename);
    }

    abstract class ConDB
    {

        private static $cnx;

        private function setConn ()
        {            
            return is_null(self::$cnx) ? self::$cnx = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=CrudConPDO","root","****") : self::$cnx;
        }

        public function getConn ()
        {
            return $this->setConn();
        }

    }
```

Tengo ahora este archivo donde estoy haciendo `CRUD`:

```
<?php

    require_once 'ConDB.class.php';

    class Crud extends ConDB
    {

        private $query;

        private function preparaEjecuta ($prepara, $ejecuta)
        {
            $this->query=$this->getConn()->prepare($prepara);
            $this->query->execute($ejecuta);
        }    

        public function insert ($table, $prepara, $ejecuta)
        {
            $stmt=$this->preparaEjecuta('INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' SET ' . $prepara . '', $ejecuta);

            return $this->getConn()->lastInsertId();
        }

        public function select ($fields, $table, $prepara, $ejecuta)
        {
            $this->preparaEjecuta('SELECT ' . $fields . ' FROM ' . $table . ' ' . $prepara . '', $ejecuta);
            return $this->query;
        }

    }
```

Me gustaría crear una función para hacer `bindParam` considerando esos datos.

Comment: Nos puedes dar un ejemplo de qué le pasas como parámetros $prepara y $ejecuta?

Comment: En mi opinión un modelo así empobrece funciones del PDO. ¿Qué tal si necesitas consultas preparadas con parámetros tipo `WHERE`? ¿En la clase de tu ejemplo, qué método usas para devolver los resultados?. Yo lo tengo organizado así: Una clase para PDO, otra para consultas SQL. Luego, en cualquier parte del programa: A. Instanciar Conexión y consultas: `$autoloader = new Autoloader(); $cnx = new MiClasePDO(); $db=$cnx->getInstance(); $sql=new MiClaseSQL();` B. Consultar y recibir los datos: `$db>query($sql->SQLINSERT($param)); $db->bind($clave, $valor); $rows = $db->resultset();`